# Is it possible to have constants of an inner class? (Java)

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

For example (using android) if I want to declare a constant of a Camera.Size class I have no apparent way of doing so. I've tried:

```
private static final Camera.Size CAMERA_SIZE = Camera.new Camera.Size(640, 480);
```

Obviously this didn't work as you need to have an instance of a camera class to call 'new' with, like so:

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Size size = mCamera.new Size(640, 480);
```

But I can't do that before before creating the constant. Is there any way around this or is it just impossible to do?

Comment: `private static final Camera.Size = Camera.new Camera.Size(640, 480);` is missing a field name between the type and `=`.

Comment: Here's where I'm lost. Do you want to set a different Camera.Size for each new instance of a Camera or are you trying to set the size for all Camera objects?

Comment: I just want a size constant that I can pass to the cameras parameters when needed, rather than writing out the values themselves. Like: params.setPictureSize(CONSTANT.width, CONSTANT.height), rather than params.setPictureSize(640, 480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

Size is a nonstatic inner class of Camera. You can only create a Size within the enclosing class Camera; you cannot construct a new Camera.Size.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/hardware/Camera.java#Camera.Size

Based on this, I'd say the API for this is written incorrectly. The constructor should have been private, or pkg private to make it clear that you cannot instantiate this class.

You don't say how you are trying to use it, but it looks like this is an object returned from various methods inside Camera. I don't see where it's ever passed into any method. Why do you need to construct it?

Comment: I don't technically have to, I want to create a default size of a picture taken by the camera. I guess the best option would be to have 2 separate constants for the width and height.

Answer (score 2):

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
private final Camera.Size size = mCamera.new Size(640, 480);
```

Comment: That doesn't really help, I want to create a constant in the scope of the class so I can't call Camera.open() before creating the constant

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Camera
 {
       public static final Camera.Size DEFAULT_SIZE = new Camera.Size(640, 480);
 }
```

you can access the constant as : **Camera.DEFAULT_SIZE**

Comment: I think you're assuming I wrote the class myself (I didn't). Sorry, I probably should have made that more clear in the description :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
private static final Camera.Size SIZE;
static {
    Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
    SIZE = mCamera.new Camera.Size(640, 480);
}
```

or ...

```
private static final Camera.Size SIZE =
    (Camera.open()).new Camera.Size(640, 480);
```

However, this all seems a bit iffy.  The object bound to `SIZE` will be tied to a `Camera` instance that isn't otherwise accessible.

I suspect that `Camera.Size` really ought to be a `static` class ... given the way that you are using it here.

```
public class Camera {
    public static class Size { ... }
    ...
    public static final Size SIZE = new Size(...);
    ...
}
```